# addthis widget for print page is not working for the first page load

Tags: javascript, addthis

I am using `addthis` widget from [addthis.com](https://www.addthis.com/).
I am using a `script` tag inside `head` tag:

```
        <script
            type="text/javascript"
            src="//s7.addthis.com/js/300/addthis_widget.js#pubid=your_pubid"
            async="async"
        ></script>
```

Now I just need to add a html with className :

```
<div className="addthis_inline_share_toolbox_3xd0" />
```

to get a **Print** and **More** options on the page, like given image below :

[image]

But the problem is, these two options are **not** showing for the **first** time page visit. If I do refresh the page, then these two options will show.
I am **not** able to find what the issue here ?

#### Note:

I have tried to move the script tag at the last of the `body` tag. But not working.
I have tried to use the `defer` option instead of `async` in script tag. But not working.

Answer (score 0):

Steps to debug this issue:

1. Make sure your code looks like this :

```html
<html>

<head></head>

<body>

    <!-- Go to www.addthis.com/dashboard to customize your tools -->
    <div class="addthis_inline_share_toolbox"></div>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://s7.addthis.com/js/300/addthis_widget.js#pubid=your_pubid"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

2. Customize `addthis` buttons at [Addthis Dashboard > Tools](https://www.addthis.com/dashboard#gallery/pub/your_pubid). Make sure `Print` and `More` button exist like this :

[image: example]